# Why is my Store API filter on productStreams.name not working?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

We're using the FAQ pro plugin and try to filter based on productStreams.name like this:

```
{
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "contains",
            "field": "productStreams.name",
            "value": "Dynamic product group name"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I receive this error:

`Accessor acris_faq_group.productStreams.name is not allowed in this api scope`

The relationship is ApiAware and can be accessed by both API's:

```
(new ManyToManyAssociationField('productStreams', ProductStreamDefinition::class, FaqGroupProductStreamDefinition::class, 'faq_group_id', 'product_stream_id'))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
```

However, the `productStreams.name` field is not accessible by both API's, even though it should be according to the ProductStreamDefinition:

```
return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            (new JsonField('api_filter', 'apiFilter'))->addFlags(new WriteProtected()),
            (new BoolField('invalid', 'invalid'))->addFlags(new WriteProtected()),

            (new TranslatedField('name'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new SearchRanking(SearchRanking::HIGH_SEARCH_RANKING)),
            (new TranslatedField('description'))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),
            (new TranslatedField('customFields'))->addFlags(new ApiAware()),

            (new TranslationsAssociationField(ProductStreamTranslationDefinition::class, 'product_stream_id'))->addFlags(new Required()),
            (new OneToManyAssociationField('filters', ProductStreamFilterDefinition::class, 'product_stream_id'))->addFlags(new CascadeDelete()),
            new OneToManyAssociationField('productCrossSellings', ProductCrossSellingDefinition::class, 'product_stream_id'),
            new OneToManyAssociationField('productExports', ProductExportDefinition::class, 'product_stream_id', 'id'),
            new OneToManyAssociationField('categories', CategoryDefinition::class, 'product_stream_id'),
        ]);
```

According to the configuration of the entities I would expect to be able to filter on the product stream name

Comment: The issue here might be that the name field is not set to be ApiAware in the ProductStreamTranslationDefinition. So I think this is a bug.